# custom part of the page print with custom stylesheet not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, printing-web-page

I have a custom part of the page print jquery function which works but not working if I add a custom stylesheet. Below is my code.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.print = function(){
        var content = '<html><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://juliver.motph.com/dist/css/ft_print.css"/></head><body>' + $(this).html() + '</body></html>';
        var w = window.open('about:blank','', '');

        w.document.write(content);
        w.print();
        w.close();
        $("#j_popup_material").removeClass("animated slideInDown").addClass("animated slideOutUp");
        $("#j_whiteshadow").fadeOut(500);
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

If I remove this part

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://juliver.motph.com/dist/css/ft_print.css"/>
```

the content on the print preview dialogue is showing but If I add it then the content is not showing, any ideas, help, clues, suggestions?

Comment: Well, there isn't such a URL `http://juliver.motph.com/dist/css/ft_print.css`.

Comment: if I browse to that url, the css did render so I'm sure its a right url. any ideas?